# cdc_acm not displaying device name for Bluetooth dongle

Tags: usb, 16.04, bluetooth

I am trying to use a Bluetooth dongle on my 64 bit Ubuntu 16, however I cannot get the device id/name of the Bluetooth dongle. After I insert the dongle, I check the *dmesg*:

```
~$ dmesg | tail
[  773.117236] cdc_acm: USB Abstract Control Model driver for USB modems and ISDN adapters
[  780.692095] usb 3-2: new full-speed USB device number 8 using xhci_hcd
[  780.969821] usb 3-2: New USB device found, idVendor=0a12, idProduct=0001
[  780.969827] usb 3-2: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[  780.969830] usb 3-2: Product: CSR8510 A10
[  853.385269] usb 3-2: USB disconnect, device number 8
[  860.196090] usb 3-2: new full-speed USB device number 9 using xhci_hcd
[  860.493780] usb 3-2: New USB device found, idVendor=0a12, idProduct=0001
[  860.493786] usb 3-2: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[  860.493789] usb 3-2: Product: CSR8510 A10
```

What I am trying to see is something like this:

```
cdc_acm 6.2:1.0 ttyACM0: USB ACM device
```

I can send data via Bluetooth, but could not receive any. And output of the *lsusb* is following:

```
~$ lsusb
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:8002 Intel Corp. 
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:800a Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 413c:2107 Dell Computer Corp. 
Bus 003 Device 009: ID 0a12:0001 Cambridge Silicon Radio, Ltd Bluetooth Dongle (HCI mode)
Bus 003 Device 005: ID 046d:c063 Logitech, Inc. DELL Laser Mouse
Bus 003 Device 004: ID 0bda:0184 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTS5182 Card Reader
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

As in [CDC_ACM not firing](https://askubuntu.com/questions/209605/cdc-acm-not-firing), I tried to activate and deactivate the cdc_acm, but it did not help. Is there a way to find the device id (something like /dev/ttyACM0). I need that id.
Any suggestions? Thanks!

PS: I am dual booting Windows 7 and Ubuntu if it makes any difference.

Comment: Is the bluetooth connected to a USB hub?  It looks to be disconnecting from the computer, something I see when using a hub

Comment: sorry for the late answer, yes, it is connected via USB.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, the cdc-acm is for serial<->usb adapters (includes usb modems or any other device that uses USB as a bridge for a TTL or RS232 serial port).

For a bluetooth dongle on ubuntu 16.04 you are probably looking for "bluetoothctl".

Comment: Hmm, mine is connected via USB. Nevertheless, I tried "bluetoothctl" too, but don't get useful information there. I can see the mac address though, is there a way to find the device id (something like /dev/ttyACM0). I need that id.

Comment: Sorry, it wasn't stated in my question before, please see the edited version

Comment: Well, you can establish a "serial like" connection using a bluetooth dongle, but it´s nothing like cdc-acm, and it depends on the device you are connecting to. There is no serial port between your PC and the bluetooth dongle itself. Please, tell us to what device (not the dongle) you want to establish a serial connection to. PS: you can type "help" on the bluetoothctl prompt to get help on what you can do with it.